Online outline appears when uploading German Alkis 3D building data as CityGML (LOD2) into QGIS with the 3d CityDB Tools
I am trying to upload 3D Data into QGIS with the 3D City Database. I followed the complete guide and installed PostgreSQL - made database and schema and imported the CityGML data with the 3D city DB. But everytime I connect with the database over QGIS and import the layers, I only get 2D outlines as a result. Why this is happening?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
